# Loop filters for all items in table column of excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to build a code that will filter a table by product type, of which there might be multiple items. I need the table to filter through each of the product types to build a hierarchy for each product family.

I'm thinking it should be something like:

```
Sub familyfilter()

 With ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1)

  For Each Item In .Columns(1)

    .AutoFilter.ShowAllData

    .Columns(1).autofilterrange.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=Item

    '[insert sub call here for hierarchy]

  Next Item
 End With
End Sub
```

I won't know the values in the family column, so I can't set a list of values to cycle through.

So if anyone knows how to do this for all the items in the column, I'd appreciate it!!

Thanks

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do. What should the end result look like? Can you give an example with apples and bananas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, I see what the issue is.  Since you are doing `For each Item in .Columns(1)`, it's only going to look in the COLUMN altogether.  A quick test is this:

```
Sub test()
Dim cel as Range
for each cel in columns(1)
    cel.select
next cel
end sub()
```

If you go through that line by line (using F8), you'll see it select the column once, loop then end.

The fix is to use a range, instead of a column:

```
Sub test()
Dim rng as range, cel as Range
Set rng = Range(Cells(1,1),cells([lastRow],1))

For each cel in rng
  ' Do whatever in the cell
Next cel

end if
end sub
```

For the last row, you have multiple options to get it.  If your data is in one 'solid' table (i.e. no blanks in column 1 until you reach the end of your data), you can use this to get the last cell, `lastCell = Cells(1,1).End(xldown).Row`.  Or, if you do have some gaps in Col. 1, `lastCell = Cells(1048576,1).End(xlup).Row`.

Edit: This should get you started - I'm not sure if the filter part will work in this loop, so you may need to put that outside of it, but let me know if the above helps.

Comment: Thanks! The problem was with defining as a range.